# Odoo - Override default company view

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am using odoo 10e. I want to change companies form and tree view. So i was following this tutorial 
[Help](https://supportuae.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/override-a-odoo-field-label-in-an-xml-view/)

and this is what i tried but its not working

```
<odoo>
<data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_crm_lead_form_inherited">
        <field name="model">res.company</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_company_form" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="name" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="string">Custodian Name</attribute>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
</odoo>
```

I see that company model have a field `name`and i am trying to override default label of name fields.

**Edit**

**__manifest__.py**

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   {
    'name': "Test",

'summary': """
    Short (1 phrase/line) summary of the module's purpose, used as
    subtitle on modules listing or apps.openerp.com""",

'description': """
    Long description of module's purpose
""",

'author': "Ancient",
'website': "http://www.google.com",

# Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
# Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/master/odoo/addons/base/module/module_data.xml
# for the full list
'category': 'Accounting',
'version': '0.1',

# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
'depends': ['base', 'mail'],

# always loaded
'data': [
    'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'security/amgl_security.xml',
    'views/views.xml',
    'views/customer.xml',
    'views/dashboard.xml',
    'views/products.xml',
    'views/order.xml',
    'views/order_line.xml',
    'views/metal_movement.xml',
    'views/possible_solutions.xml',
    'views/possible_reasons.xml',
    'views/pending_accounts.xml',
    'views/dealer.xml',
    'emailTemplates/mmr_create_mail.xml',
    'emailTemplates/reject_mmr_email.xml',
    'emailTemplates/mmr_approval_complete.xml',
    'emailTemplates/mmr_approve_reject_button.xml',
    'report/metal_movement_template.xml',
    'report/metal_movement_view.xml',
    'views/res_company.xml'
],
'qweb': [
    "views/colspan.xml",
],
# only loaded in demonstration mode
'demo': [
    'demo/demo.xml',
    'demo/customer_view.xml'
]
}
```

Comment: Have you provided the path to this file in your `__manifest__.py`?

Comment: Yes i do, just forgot to mention in question

Comment: hmm, try to set up primary mode, i.e. add `<field name="mode">primary</field>` before `arch`

Comment: tired, but this doesn't make any difference !!!!

Comment: Why do you want to change the field name string attribute?

Comment: @jo541 Yes, string attribute for field `name` is `Company Name` right now. I want to change it to `Custodian Name`

Comment: Can you provide your manifest file and the error you get?

Comment: @CZoellner Let me update my question with __manifest__ and i am not getting any error. Its just not updating. Even i can see my inherited view in `Inherited Views` section.

Comment: Just wondering: isn't `name` a required field for `ir.ui.view`?

Comment: @CZoellner Yes it is required

Comment: I seeing a little strength think. Your id of your record is "view_crm_lead_form_inherited", are you sure, it's the good id or it's a bad copy past of on other record declarations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the important part of the origin view:

```xml
<div class="oe_title">
    <label for="name" class="oe_edit_only"/>
    <h1>
        <field name="name" class="oe_inline"/>
    </h1>
    <label for="rml_header1" class="oe_edit_only"/>
    <h3>
        <field name="rml_header1" placeholder="e.g. Global Business Solutions"/>
    </h3>
</div>
```

You have to change the label, because the field label, which you try to override, is never used.

Following should work:

```xml
<label for="name" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="string">Custodian Name</attribute>
    <attribute name="for" />
</label>
```

Comment: ok, this works. By using same approach can we also change the menu name and its title which show right above the create button in tree view ?

Comment: That should work, too. The model is `ir.ui.menu` and the external id you're looking for is `base.menu_action_res_company_form`.

Comment: Thanks Man appreciate your help!